# How to merge svg shape with a svg text

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Im having problems trying to merge a svg text with an svg shape.
This is my current code, the white bar only turn grey when my pointer is in the box, but when it is on the letter, the box turned back white. How do i make it so that it will remain grey even though my mouse is on the text until I move my pointer away from the text and the box. I've tried putting the functions in the `<g>`,`<a>`,`<svg>` tags but it simply won't work.

```
<script>
    function ontop(x){
        x.style.fill = "#c8cace"
    }

    function notOnTop(x){
        x.style.fill = "white"
    }
</script>

    <svg>
    <g>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" >
        <rect height="50px" width="350px" x="70%" y="14%" fill="white" rx="5px" onmouseenter="ontop(this)" onmouseleave="notOnTop(this)" />
        <text x="72%" y="22%" font-size="20" fill="black" >Google</text>
        </a>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the text the property pointer-events: none so that it is ignored by the mouse.

Note that you don't need javascript to do hovering CSS :hover will do that.

```css
rect {
    fill: white;
}

rect:hover {
    fill: #c8cace;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" >
        <rect height="50px" width="350px" x="70%" y="14%" rx="5px" />
        <text x="72%" y="22%" font-size="20" fill="black" pointer-events="none">Google</text>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the text behind the rectangle. And make the rectangle semitransparent.

```
<svg width="5cm" height="4cm" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <script>
    function ontop(x){
        x.style.fill = "#c8cace"
    }

    function notOnTop(x){
        x.style.fill = "white"
    }
  </script>
    <g>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" >
        <text x="72%" y="22%" font-size="20" fill="black" >Google2</text>
        <rect height="50px" width="350px" x="70%" y="14%" fill="white" rx="5px" opacity="0.5"
        onmouseenter="ontop(this)" onmouseleave="notOnTop(this)"/>
    </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Edit1**

SVG namespace is added to make it work as standalone svg file.

Comment: SVG namespace is added. Now it should work. Tested on Google Chrome, MS Edge.

Comment: @LeeJingYong It would be helpful if you describe why it didn't work and how you use it. Originally, it works well as embedded SVG, but not as a standalone.

Comment: now its working but i dont want the rectangle to semitransparent, i prefer the answer above